# How can I tell pytest which tests to run?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to run all Python tests which are in [coding-horror/basic-computer-games](https://github.com/coding-horror/basic-computer-games) automatically via the github CI. However, when I run `pytest .` in this repository, something seems broken. Even after 2 minutes pytest still says:

```
============================== test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/moose/Github/basic-computer-games, configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: mccabe-2.0, icdiff-0.5, cov-3.0.0, timeout-2.1.0
collecting 0 items
```

This simple script finds all test files in 0.1s:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def find_test_files(root: Path):
    for p in root.rglob("*"):
        if (
            not p.is_file()
            or not p.name.endswith(".py")
            or not p.name.startswith("test_")
        ):
            continue
        yield p


for p in find_test_files(Path(".")):
    print(p)
```

How can I tell pytest to use only those files?

edit: The original issue is found and fixed ([PR](https://github.com/coding-horror/basic-computer-games/pull/654) - infinite loops on module level). Still, I'm curious how I can tell pytest **programatically with Python** which files to use for running the tests.

Comment: I found the issue: Somebody wrote a python file (`90_Tower/python/tower.py`) with an infitite game loop directly on the module level. Still, I'd be interested if changing the pytest test collection would be possible.

Comment: This is not an issue of the tests or the pytest framework. In any case you will have to import that module at some point to test it and it will get stuck. Even if you would use an extra thread that thread would be stuck. What could be helpful is to put the import into the test itself, you would see the problematic test then.

Comment: I know. I am currently fixing those modules. Still, I had the case in the past where I wanted to tell pytest which paths it should look at for files. Not via bash, but via Python as those paths were not static (like here, where all folders which are not "python" folders can be ignored)

Comment: If you want to use a subset of the files that pytest finds itself, you could implement `pytest_collection_modifyitems` and filter the wanted tests out.